# Create export of computed types in file

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if it is possible given a file with an exported type, could the types be *extracted* from the generic, to a *computed* type?

```
function example() {
  return {
    foo: 'hi',
    bar: true,
    baz: 1
  };
}

export type Signature = ReturnType<typeof example>;
```

To this:

```
export type Signature = {
    foo: string;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: number;
}
```

I don't believe that the `tsc` cli does this, and I'm not sure what this process would be called.

Can `tsc` create this export?

Are there any third-party tools that can do this?

The only way I know how to do this is hover over the variable in VSCode and copy the computed type, and that only works if it's short, and doesn't trail off ...

I found some other references to similar requests:

- [Option to expand computed TypeScript types on hover](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94679)
- [Is it possible to display the full computed type of a typescript type/interface in VSCode (or elsewhere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595116/is-it-possible-to-display-the-full-computed-type-of-a-typescript-type-interface)
- [VS code how to show full typescript definition on mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508909/vs-code-how-to-show-full-typescript-definition-on-mouse-hover)
- [Show full type in typescript type hover hint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76480)
- [Add full type hover popup to VS Code commands](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35601)
- [Interactive Diagnostics](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64566)

Answer (score 6):

Looking into this question, without replicating VSCode's [`hover.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/languageFeatures/hover.ts), I find that one, if not the only, answer to this question is:

## Extract that hover "quickinfo" from `tsserver`

You need to communicate the line and char offset in your file to the server. One should be able to use [abstract syntax tree (AST)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) in `.ts` for that. I wrote a client in bash instead. Attached below, it supports calculating char offset from column (as seen in the VSCode statusbar). A log from a run of your source and a document position on the word "Signature" follows and the end comes very close to your wanted extraction.

```sh
$ (prepared=('open -s #.ts -i file' 'quickinfo -s #.ts -i file -n 9 -i line -n 20 -i _column_')&&. $(which tsssh))
ts < open -s #.ts -i file
{"seq": 1, "type": "request", "command": "open", "arguments": {"file": "#.ts"}}
ts < quickinfo -s #.ts -i file -n 9 -i line -n 20 -i _column_
{"seq": 1, "type": "request", "command": "quickinfo", "arguments": {"file": "#.ts", "line": 9, "offset": 19}}
event #0
event: typingsInstallerPid
body: {"pid": 65341}
response #0 (1)
command: quickinfo
body: {"kind": "type", "kindModifiers": "export", "start": {"line": 9, "offset": 13}, "end": {"line": 9, "offset": 22}, "displayString": "type Signature = {\n    foo: string;\n    bar: boolean;\n    baz: number;\n}", "documentation": "", "tags": []}
displayString: type Signature = {
    foo: string;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: number;
}
```

- Quick and dirty client for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29..
- Relies heavily on prerequisite http://kmkeen.com/jshon/, and compatible bash and gawk, while tput and tee could be cut out I guess..
- Developed on macOS 10.13.6 in version **5.0.16** `bash -O cmdhist -O lithist` with macports, and various other shopt..
- NB: You need to poll event/response manually by sending empty commandlines. Exit with kill -sigint , typically ctrl+C..
- Run in local repo like `tsserver=./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver tsssh`..
- Disable history with `histfile= path/to/tsssh`. Multiple "prepared" can be specified as `(prepared=("first" ... "last")&&. path/to/tsssh)`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
( # Quick and dirty client for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29..
  # Relies heavily on prerequisite http://kmkeen.com/jshon/, and compatible bash and gawk, while tput and tee could be cut out I guess..
  # Developed on macOS 10.13.6 in version 5.0.16 `bash -O cmdhist -O lithist` with macports, and various other shopt..
  # NB: You need to poll event/response manually by sending empty commandlines. Exit with kill -sigint , typically ctrl+C..
  # Run in local repo like `tsserver=./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver tsssh`..
  # Disable history with `histfile='' path/to/tsssh`. Multiple "prepared" can be specified as `(prepared=("first" ... "last")&&. path/to/tsssh)`
  # Copyright 2020 Viktor Bergquist (vike2000@gmail.com), license https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
  HISTFILE=${histfile-.tsssh_history} &&
  { ((\!-( x = xtrace )))||set -x ;} && ((!errexit))||set -e &&
  state()(set +x;tput setaf $1;echo "${*:2}";tput sgr0;((\!-x))||set -x) >&2 && trap 'state 1 $?: "$BASH_COMMAND"' err &&
  [[ ! $HISTFILE ]]||{ h=$HISTSIZE&&HISTSIZE=1&&set -o history&&HISTSIZE=$h&&history -s ''&&{ history -r "$HISTFILE"||:;};}&&
  coproc ts (${tsserver:-tsserver}) &&set -o pipefail&&command sleep 1 &&
  show(){ set +x; f=$1&&shift && i=$(cat) && declare -n n&&for n;do
      n=$(((\!-x))||set -x; jshon <<<"$i" -e "${!n}" $f);((e=$?)) || echo "${!n}: $n"; done; ((\!-x))||set -x; return $e;} &&
  extract(){ show "$@";} >/dev/null &&
  compact()( "$@"|gawk -vORS= '{sub("^\\s+",!m[0]?"":" ")}1;{match($0,",$",m)}END{printf"\n"}') &&
  function check(){ while {
        read -rt.1 -d$'\r' h&&[[ $h =~ Content-Length:\ ([0-9]+) ]]&&read -r$t -N3&&read -r$t -N$((${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-1)) a;} <&${ts[0]};do
      #set +x;echo 'ts > '"$a";((\!-x))||set -x
                <<<"$a" extract -u type seq &&case $type in
      (   event)state 2 $type \#$seq
                <<<"$a" show -u event ;;&
      (response)<<<"$a" extract -u success request_seq&&case $success in
        ( false)state 1 $type \#$seq "($request_seq)"
                <<<"$a" show -u command message ;;
        (  true)state 2 $type \#$seq "($request_seq)"
                <<<"$a" show -u command message metadata 2>/dev/null ;;
        (     *)state 1 "unknown success: $success" ;esac ;&
      (   event)<<<"$a" compact show '' body ;! [[ $type = response && $success = true ]]||case $command in
        (     *)<<<"$a" extract '' body ;;&
        ( quickinfo) <<< "$body" show -u displayString ;esac ;;
      (       *)state 1 "unknown type: $type" ;esac ;done;} &&
  seq=0 && for p in ${!prepared[@]} -1;do for fd in <(echo "${prepared[p]}") 0;do fd="${fd##*/}"; (((p<0)!=(0<fd)))||continue
      while check <&-; set +x; read -p 'ts < ' -era Q; do
        ((\!${#Q[*]}))&&{ tput -S<<<$'cuu1\nel'
          ((\!-x))||set -x;} ||
        { ((\!-x))||set -x
          history -s "${Q[*]}"&&{ [[ ! $HISTFILE ]]||{ [[ ! -a $HISTFILE ]]&&history -w "$HISTFILE"||history -a "$HISTFILE";};} &&
          d=$(compact jshon <<<{} -n$((++seq)) -i seq -s request -i type -s "$Q" -i command -n {} "${Q[@]:1}" -i arguments)
          A=$(compact jshon <<<{} "${Q[@]:1}")
          ! <<<"$A" extract -u file line _column_ 2>/dev/null ||
          { o=$(gawk -vT="${tabs:-4}" -vC="$_column_" FNR=="$line"'{
              t=-1;for(o=0;o<=length();o++){t++;if("\t"==substr($0,o,1)){t+=T-1;t-=t%T}if(t>=C)break}print o-1
              }' "$file") &&
            d=$(<<<"$d" compact jshon -e arguments -d _column_ -n "$o" -i offset -p);}
          tee   <<<"$d" /dev/stderr >&${ts[1]};}
        done<&$fd;done;done;set +x;echo bye) #ts < eg: reload -s index.ts -i file ^M quickinfo -s index.ts -i file -n 4 -i line -n 7 -i _column_
```

---

With all your question's good references, you surely know some "trail off" that you mention can be prevented with `"compilerOptions":{"noErrorTruncation":true}` in the `tsconfig.json` :)

To the end of those references I can add that there's also an [Interactive Diagnostics PR 31384 (draft)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31384) to hope for :)

For the time being I'll look into the interesting utility type in the related Q&A [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type/57683652#57683652)